# Blurred places in TextField

Tags: java, javafx-8

When i'm creating TextField in my App then in it then there are places where appears blur.

Example: 1.There is a blur at the beginning of input :

[image]

2. After a few taps on Space blur disappears:

[image]

3. Last character display distortion:

[image]

Then the blur appears again, and this happens throughout the field.
I don't understand why this is happens and hox fix it

Code of fragment if this need:

```
private void inputSaveName() {

   Stage nameStage = new Stage();
   nameStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
   nameStage.initOwner(saveStage);
   nameStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
   nameStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

   BorderPane saveBorder = new BorderPane();
   saveBorder.setStyle("-fx-background-color:saddlebrown;" +"-fx-border-width:5;" + "-fx-border-radius:16;" + "-fx-font-family: Cambria;" + "-fx-border-color:olive");
   Scene nameScene = new Scene (saveBorder,300,120);
   nameScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300,120);
   rect.setArcHeight(40.0);
   rect.setArcWidth(40.0);
   saveBorder.setClip(rect);

   Button acceptNameButton = new Button("Accept");
   Button cancelNameButton = new Button("Cancel");

   acceptNameButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkkhaki;" + "-fx-background-insets: 0 2 2 0;" + "-fx-padding: 8;" + "-fx-font-size:15;" + "-fx-text-alignment: 

center");
   cancelNameButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkkhaki;" + "-fx-background-insets: 0 0 2 2;" + "-fx-padding: 8;" + "-fx-font-size:15;" + "-fx-text-alignment: 

center");

   cancelNameButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  
     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {

       nameStage.close();
     }
   });

   TextField nameField = new TextField();
   nameField.setPromptText("Write save name");
   nameField.setFont(new Font(18));

   HBox buttonBox = new HBox();
   buttonBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

   buttonBox.setHgrow(acceptNameButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
   buttonBox.setHgrow(cancelNameButton, Priority.ALWAYS);

   acceptNameButton.setMaxWidth(130);
   cancelNameButton.setMaxWidth(130);

   buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(acceptNameButton,cancelNameButton);
  

   saveBorder.setBottom(buttonBox);
   saveBorder.setCenter(nameField);

   nameStage.setScene(nameScene);
   nameStage.show();


 }
```

Comment: There is no difference between the two images, except the caret position, maybe you're talking about the focus blue border ?

Comment: Blur really is in the first screenshot. :)
 I’m sorry to see him so poorly. I added another screenshot with a graphic artifact in TextField.

Comment: I can see the difference now, I'm not sure but I think it has something to do with the glyphes's arrangement !

Comment: How i can control this? I really don't have ideas

Answer (score 1):

i just try ur code locally :

```
public class test2 extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Stage nameStage = new Stage();
    nameStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
   // nameStage.initOwner(saveStage);
    nameStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    nameStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    BorderPane saveBorder = new BorderPane();
    saveBorder.setStyle("-fx-background-color:saddlebrown;" + "-fx-border-width:5;" + "-fx-border-radius:16;" + "-fx-font-family: Cambria;" + "-fx-border-color:olive");
    Scene nameScene = new Scene(saveBorder, 300, 120);
    nameScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300, 120);
    rect.setArcHeight(40.0);
    rect.setArcWidth(40.0);
    saveBorder.setClip(rect);

    Button acceptNameButton = new Button("Accept");
    Button cancelNameButton = new Button("Cancel");

    acceptNameButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkkhaki;" +
            "-fx-background-insets: 0 2 2 0;" + "-fx-padding: 8;" + "-fx-font-size:15;" +
            "-fx-text-alignment: center");
    cancelNameButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkkhaki;" +
            "-fx-background-insets: 0 0 2 2;" + "-fx-padding: 8;" +
            "-fx-font-size:15;" + "-fx-text-alignment: center");

    cancelNameButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {

            nameStage.close();
        }
    });

    TextField nameField = new TextField();
    nameField.setPromptText("Write save name");
    nameField.setFont(new Font(18));

    HBox buttonBox = new HBox();
    buttonBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    buttonBox.setHgrow(acceptNameButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
    buttonBox.setHgrow(cancelNameButton, Priority.ALWAYS);

    acceptNameButton.setMaxWidth(130);
    cancelNameButton.setMaxWidth(130);

    buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(acceptNameButton, cancelNameButton);


    saveBorder.setBottom(buttonBox);
    saveBorder.setCenter(nameField);

    nameStage.setScene(nameScene);
    nameStage.show();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args); } 
}
```

nothing wrong with this code, and no artifact on my screen

[image]

maybe something wrong with ur gpu, or ur javafx
i am using jdk 14.0.1, javafx 14 with gradle, maybe u need move on to the latest version :)

Comment: I asked my friends launch this app on this PC and one had this problem, and the other really didn't have it either. Maybe this problem really lies in the computer software

Comment: why u not using scenebuilder with fxml ?

Comment: I'm starting learn JavaFX recently and for a better understanding, I decided to work this way at first. Maybe this strange but for me it is really more convenient